# Downloading video file from UIWebView

Tags: ios, video, download, uiwebview

In my application I want to download video say .MP4 format from any downloadable link clicked by user from UIWebView and save in applications Document folder.

Following is the code:-

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
NSURL *url = [[webView request] URL];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
 [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest: request delegate:self];

return YES;    
}
```

and response is received

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)theResponse{
NSString* content_type = [[(NSHTTPURLResponse*)theResponse allHeaderFields] valueForKey:@"Content-Type"];
NSLog(@"Content type = %@",content_type);
if ([content_type isEqualToString:@"mp4"]) {
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[theResponse URL]];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dataPath_ = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@""];
    NSString *newStr = [@"testVideo" stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@".mp4"]];
    NSString *FilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",dataPath_,newStr];
    [urlData writeToFile:FilePath atomically:YES];

}
}
```

The first time when clicked on Download link The MIME type is always 'text/html', the video plays and when clicked on back, then MIME type 'video' is received and video starts downloading.
I want the video to download on first click.

I'd appreciate some help or sample code.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?